# javascript Request.QueryString

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, query-string

How do I request querystring using javascript from URL

**e.g : http://localhost:1247/portal/alias__MySite/lang__en/tabid__3381/default.aspx**

I want to get **tabid**...

```
 var tabid = '<%= Request.QueryString["tabid"] %> ';
```

Above code works only in aspx page
 but i dont need it, any ideas? thanks

Comment: As I wrote in my answer, I doubt you are looking for a QueryString because there is a rewrite mechanism on the server. You need to parse the URL if you want to get the number.

Answer (score 2):

There is now a new api `URLSearchParams`. Use that in conjunction with `window.location.search`

```
var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
console.log(urlParams.get('tabid'));
```

If your browser does not support `URLSearchParams`, you can create a custom fallback function:

```
function getParam(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, '\\[').replace(/[\]]/, '\\]');
    var regex = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)');
    var results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? '' : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
};
console.log(getParam('tabid'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know why but I've always found the javascript for querystring data fetching a bit hacky. if you don't need this value on the initial page load then perhaps you could use Request.QueryString in the code and set the value to a hidden field, which your javascript will read from?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, It is working perfectly for me.

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
   name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
   var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
    results = regex.exec(location.search);
   return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

var tabId=getParameterByName("tabid");
```

Answer (score 0):

I bet there is a server-side rewrite (DotNetNuke?), so the aspx.cs "sees" the redirection target which contains the correct QueryString.

For the client, you have to use another mechanism because the browser only "sees" the public URL. In this case, a Regex that picks the number behind 'tabid_' and before the next slash should work. This would be the same number (page id?) that the aspx page "sees".

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used:

```
<script type="text/javascript">   

function QueryString(key) {  
//Get the full querystring  
fullQs = window.location.search.substring(1);  
//Break it down into an array of name-value pairs  
qsParamsArray = fullQs.split("&");  
//Loop through each name-value pair and   
//return value in there is a match for the given key  
for (i=0;i<qsParamsArray.length;i++) {  
strKey = qsParamsArray[i].split("=");  
    if (strKey[0] == key) {  
        return strKey[1];  
    }  
}  
}  

//Test the output (Add ?fname=Cheese&lname=Pizza to your URL)  
//You can change the variable to whatever it is you need to do for example, you could  
//change firstname to id and lastname to userid and just change the reference in the
//document.write/alert box
var firstname = QueryString("fname"); 
var lastname = QueryString("lname");   
document.write("You are now logged in as " + firstname + " " + lastname + "!");  

</script>
```

You can replace document.write with alert and it would give you an alert box instead!

I used this on my website. Its not done yet but when it is it will be at zducttapestuff.com

The output will look like this: You are now logged in as Cheese Pizza!

This is very unsecure for Passwords though since the password will be shown in the url.